# deriving the profit function given probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I can't seem to get much further in deriving the profit function for part (c). I've attached the question and my attempt, but I'm not sure on what to do next, or if I've done something completely wrong.I didn't really want the answer, but just a general idea in the direction I should be going in. [questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRVDg.jpg); [my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esXho.jpg)

Comment: Check your part b) solution again for the case $X < k$. You are not required to derive the pmf of $\Pi$ in part c (and it is wrong too; you cannot obtain the pmf in that way). You just need to make use of the linearity of expectation

Comment: @BGM I attempted the question again, and [this is what I understood from it thus far](http://i.imgur.com/bHeyEkF.jpg).